# What is the meaning of the semicolon in $f(x;\Theta)$?

Tags: probability, notation

In section 6.2, in the second paragraph of p. 335 (image below) of ["Probability and statistical inference 7e" by Hogg and Tanis](http://books.google.com/books?id=DG-6QgAACAAJ&dq=9780131464131&hl=en&sa=X&ei=bBfiT8WtJqbs2QXXv527Cw&ved=0CEIQ6AEwAA) states:

> perhaps it is known that $f(x;\Theta)=(1/\Theta)e^{x/\Theta}$

where $x$ is data and $\Theta$ is a parameter.

What does "$;$" mean in this context, as opposed to "$,$" or "$|$", all three are used in different ways in the same textbook ("," and ";" are used on the same page, $|$ in the standard statement of Bayes' Theorem)?

I think I understand "$,$" and "$|$" and I read $f(x,\Theta)$ as "function of data and parameters" and $f(x|\Theta)$ as "function of the data given parameters".

Here is a scan of the page for more context:

[image]